# Eliminar todos los caracteres excepto los últimos 5 de cada linea con sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Con este comando elimino los últimos 5 caracteres de cada linea.
Quisiera saber como seria la inversa.

```
$ sed -i".bak" "s/.....$//p" input.txt
```

Quiero tener los últimos 5 caracteres de cada linea.

Comment: nótese que haciendo `sed ".../p"` estás imprimiendo las líneas que quieres dos veces. Seguramente querrías hacer `sed -n` para que solo imprima las líneas que coinciden.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza esto.

```
sed -r 's/.*(.{5})$/\1/' archivo
```

Lo que hago es básico, simplemente capturo un grupo de 5 caracteres entre una cantidad 'x' de caracteres y el final de la línea y luego lo imprimo.

Primero pruebalo sin el parámetro `-i`.

Comment: podrías mejorar la expresion indicándole un rango de 1 a 5 en la captura de caracteres en caso tal de que existan lineas de menos de 5 caracteres

Comment: @nauseantparrot Claro, pero el caso es que especificó con `sed` y 5 caracteres además de que su planteamiento, al menos como lo entendí, no da posibilidad a que sea menor a esa cantidad.

Comment: el código lo hace, sin embargo no estaba especificado textualmente, ya lo ajuste

Comment: Claro, ambos códigos lo hacen, el problema siempre fue de cómo interpretaba el planteamiento cada quien, si como "**solo 5**" o "**a lo más 5**", lo mismo con el caso de `sed` si es "sólo con `sed`" o con "algo semejante a lo haría `sed`"

Comment: Digamos que dejó abierta a muchas posibilidades para usar múltiples regex, programas, etc.

Comment: `/g` no hace falta aquí, solo puedes hacer la sustitución una vez por línea

Comment: ¡Claro, gracias! Lo tomé por costumbre.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener el resultado deseado de una forma sencilla con `grep` haciendo uso de los flags `-o` (solo muestra el texto que concuerda con la expresion) y `-E` (extiende el uso de expresiones regulares).

```sh
grep -oE '.{1,5}$' input.txt > salida
```

De esta forma es posible obtener los 5 últimos caracteres o menos en caso tal de que alguna fila tenga una longitud inferior.

Comment: qué buena idea, muy bien resuelto. Mejor grep que sed en este caso, efectivamente